# Node Send data from server to client (already loaded '/' index page) after sometime from '/webhook' another end point/code block

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, notifications, paypal-webhooks

My intention is after user executes a third party API (PayPal for instance) on '/' page; upon receiving a data on '/webhook/check' endpoint from this Third Party API system, relay data to the '/' index page where the user is still waiting for the response.

Below are my two controllers.

#### index.js controller

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', model);
});
```

#### webhooks.js controller

```
router.post('/check', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);

    // WHEN A WEBHOOK NOTIFICATION IS RECEIVED HERE, DO SOMETHING
    // TO SEND DATA TO ALREADY LOADED `/' INDEX PAGE RENDERED BY
    // CONTROLLER ABOVE

    res.end();
});
```

Update:
I used socket.io

#### index.js

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Socket, on connection, now sending/receiving on `webhooks`' );
    // socket.join("test");
    socket.on('webhooks', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });


});

app.socketsio  = io;
```

#### webhooks.js

```
var socketsio = require('../index').socketsio;


module.exports = function (router) {

    var model = new WebhooksModel();

    router.post('/check', function (req, res) {

        // console.log(req.body);
        socketsio.emit('webhooks', req.body);
        res.end();
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EventEmitter:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', model);

    myEmitter.on('checkNotification', function(data) {
        // Process data
    })
});

router.post('/check', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);

    myEmitter.emit('checkNotification', 'Your data')

    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this. I am not sure how would I trigger an event on the client end. I'll get back to go. I have been going back and forth with using sockets.io and HTML5 Server-Sent Events. Probably use it to ping the client and fetch data instead constant polling.

Comment: SSE works only in one direction `server => clients`, so, that's good when you don't want to setup a socket's server and you need only one-direction communication channel, Socket.io is bidirectional, it can work better when the client and the server need to exchange a lot of messages and events in realtime.

Comment: I used the solution in the update section above. SSE didnt work for me.